# Can you defeat AES-CTR's birthday boundary with a 2nd AES?

Tags: aes, pseudo-random-function, ctr

This follows on from [How do I produce a stream of secure random numbers from AES-Counter mode?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15944/23115)

Consider then the generator:-

$$
 \operatorname{AES_{k1}}(n) \oplus  \operatorname{AES_{k2}}(n)
$$

where    $  k1 \ne k2  $, and  $n$ is the single counter variable. And we take care to ensure that there is no relationship between $k1$ and $k2$. If this  really does create a pseudo random function, will the  birthday boundary for AES-CTR output be overcome?

Comment: Related and helpful: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5447/32035

Comment: @hardyrama Indeed very.  Apologies for the repetition then.  I haven't used the PRF acronym so the _related_ ones didn't pop up when I authored it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The number of $n$-bit blocks you can encrypt with this construction is proportional to $2^n$ instead of just $2^{n/2}$. So for AES this shouldn't be a problem because you can't process anything near $2^{128}$ blocks.

A secure stream cipher can be constructed from a PRF using something similar to AES-CTR.

AES is more accurately described as a PRP than a PRF, but this distinction is unimportant if the number of queries an attacker is allowed to make under a given key is much much less than $2^{64}$.

<sub>(See PRF switching lemma. If the number of queries the attacker can make is much less than $2^{n/2}$, then it is safe to substitute an $n$-bit PRP for a PRF. This is where AES-CTR's limit comes from.)</sub>

However it has been proven that the XOR of two PRPs is a secure PRF instead for up to $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$ queries. <sup>[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830075411/https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-2523.pdf) [2](https://eprint.iacr.org/1999/024)</sup>

Readers should note that this isn't the same as saying that you can use up to *precisely* $2^n$ blocks. For this reason, I strongly discourage using a block cipher algorithm with smaller blocks (like DES, Simon, or Speck) in this kind of construct. (Or any other mode, I suppose.)

Comment: Are you sure that 2 instance of AES-CTR xor'd together gives $2^n$ blocks for the bound? Unless I am misreading something, that appears to directly contradict with [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5452/29554), which claims security up to $2^{2b/3}$ queries for the construction

Comment: @EllaRose One of the papers I linked to cites Lucks for prior work. (As well as another paper that improved on Lucks' bounds.) Each of these sources, I think, give a minimum number of queries an attacker needs to make. Lucks provided a bound on how few q the best possible attack must require. Subsequent work provided tighter bounds. None were numbers from actual discovered attacks. "At least this difficult" in other words.